# Is every finite group finitely presented? (From Michael Artin's book)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, relations, free-groups, finitely-generated

The question is:

> Can every finite group G be presented by a finite set of generators and a finite set of relations?

I think the answer is yes, but I can't find a general way to decompose every finite groups into generators and relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is indeed yes: Consider the finite set of relations
$$R:=\{g_1g_2g_3^{-1}\mid (g_1g_2=g_3)(g_1,g_2,g_3\in G)\}.$$
Then $\langle G\mid R\rangle$ is a presentation of $G$ with a finite set of generators $G$, and a finite set of relations $R$.